# Proving that two vector spaces of equal dimension are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-space-isomorphism

Given the following problem

> Let $U$ and $V$ be finite dimensional vector spaces, such that $\dim(U) = \dim(V)$. Prove that $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic.

I was just wondering if somebody could critique and validate my proof.

#### Proof

Two vector spaces $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists a bijection $\phi: U \to V$. That is, an invertible linear map between the two. Let $\dim(U) = \dim(V) = n$ and let $\left\{u_1, \dots, u_n\right\}$ and $\left\{v_1, \dots, v_n\right\}$ be bases for $U$ and $V$, respectively. It follows that any vector $u \in U$ can be written as

$$
u = c_1u_1 + \cdots + c_nu_n
$$

We define $\phi: U \to V$ as

$$
\phi(c_1u_1 + \cdots + c_nu_n) = c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n
$$

Observe that $\phi$ is invertible. That is, given a vector

$$
v = d_1v_1 + \cdots + d_nv_n
$$

in $V$, we define $\phi^{-1}: V \to U$ as

$$
\phi^{-1}(d_1v_1 + \cdots + d_nv_n) = d_1u_1 + \cdots + d_nu_n
$$

Since there exists a bijection between $U$ and $V$, they are isomorphic.

Comment: your proof is pretty good except that at the end you should say "since there is a linear bijection". it is pretty obvious that your map is linear, as you mention. however the isomorphism concept is about preserving structure, and so in any discussions of isomorphism the relevant structure should always be kept to the forefront of attention

Comment: Our professor always just uses the term "bijection" since it is a linear algebra course and linear bijections are the only type of bijections we study. However, I will change it to "linear bijection" to be more rigorous. Thank you very much!

Comment: all the best with your studies! i love math, but sometimes suffer from short-circuit of the brain which leads me to make bizarre assertions! i'm trying to learn to be more careful and thorough.

Comment: You might want to write “can be written *uniquely* as”, otherwise $\phi$ would not be well-defined.

Comment: You need to mention (or show a little) bit why the map $\varphi$ that you defined is linear. And then you need to mention again that by the same argumen the inverse map that you defined is linear as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common theorem that qualifies as
• Theorem 6.25 on P512 of *Linear Algebra* by David Poole,
• [Theorem 3.18 on P55](http://books.google.com/books?id=ovIYVIlithQC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=ISomorphic+dim+V+%3D+dim+W&source=bl&ots=BWZ_l86o14&sig=1pT0pRu6XH61f88CAXsSJNXRZhc&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=1GysUrD_NKnpiAffnIHwDA&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAjgU#v=onepage&q=ISomorphic%20dim%20V%20%3D%20dim%20W&f=false) of *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Sheldon Axler,
• and can be found here at [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=pX4XDZbr1oIC&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=ISomorphic+dim+V+%3D+dim+W&source=bl&ots=LKk97OIq7O&sig=vtq1Y_m3LdT6tZ8JSbAilEWvehY&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=oGmsUv-1MMOgigf9-YG4Bw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=ISomorphic%20dim%20V%20%3D%20dim%20W&f=false).

Also, in your first line, I think that you should specify $\phi$ to be a bijective linear transformation, and not just a bijection. I hope that this helps.